# How to return true if string is found in a file using awk?

Tags: shell-script, awk, grep

I have a file that looks like this:

```
xxxxx,aaaaaa,abab21323,ccccccc
```

I need a script that runs some command if a file contains a string given as a variable. If not, do some other commands.

This is my bash code:

```
#!/bin/bash
var1=$1

if grep -Fq "$var1" Agenda.txt
then

## SOME COMMANDS

else
## SOME OTHER COMMANDS
fi
```

It works, but I wish to do the same using only `awk`.

Comment: Can you explain why you need to do this in awk? Launching system commands is much easier in the shell. If you really absolutely _must_ do it in awk, please tell us the commands you need to run because the details might change the way we need to write the awk script. What have you got so far? Do you have any awk code to share?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, i would love to add a bounty to this question, not sure how to do that.

I must do this in awk unfortunately. First i had to do this program in bash, which i already completed, but now i have to do it in awk which i find extremely hard to understand.

The program needs to do this in AWK:

When run, a string is given by parameter,
the program will check if the string is found in a file that contains 4 colums delimited by "-"
if the string is found, ask the user if he wants to delete the line where the string occurs,
if not found just say "not found"

Comment: is this an assignment or exercise? Look into the `exit` command and `END` blocks in AWK.

Comment: It is an exercise which is taking way more time than it was supposed to, and honestly i dont feel like i want to spend more time in this AWK thing, bash is so easy and straightforward for me.

this is why i am seeking for help

Comment: I'm afraid you cannot offer a bounty: bounties come out of a user's reputation and sine since you're new here, you don't have any reputation to offer yet. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties. That said, do you need to do _everything_ in awk, from the beginning to the end, including running the commands or can you just use `awk` for the matching?

Answer (score 3):

Something like that (according with the `-F` and `-q` grep options):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
var1=$1

if awk -v var1="$var1" 'index($0,var1)>0 {r=1;exit} END{exit r!=1}' Agenda.txt
then

## SOME COMMANDS

else
## SOME OTHER COMMANDS
fi
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.
looks like it is partially working.

this is a line of agenda file:

9348932-Mark-Red-markred@gmail.com

looks like if VAR1 is "Mark", then it will be found correctly, but it will be found correctly even if the VAR1 is just "Ma"

Comment: @user549209 yes, that's exactly how your `grep` version works. If you don't want that, please edit your question and clarify. Ideally, show us an example input and the output you would expect from it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i just tested and you are right, then i will check how to change that grep first.... thanks a lot anyways...